# Small Following system. How to select two different values from a column

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm working on a small project similar to, let's say, Twitter, where somebody can follow you and you can follow others.
I'm trying to figure out how to show which people a person is following.

An example:

login

```
ID    username 
 1     jhon
 2     bob
 3     james
 4     kate
```

followers (sta stands for stalker and fol for following)

```
ID  idsta  idfol
 1   1      3
 2   1      4
 3   2      1
 4   3      4
 5   3      1
 6   3      2
 7   4      2
```

I managed to write a some-what working query, but for the "fol" table it shows just one person and not every person that is following.

```
SELECT sta, fol 
FROM (SELECT login.username
       FROM login, followers
       WHERE login.id = 3 and login.id=followers.idsta) AS sta,
      (SELECT login.username
      FROM login,followers
      WHERE login.id = 2 and login.id=followers.idfol) AS fol
```

And I would like to show me something like :

```
User    Following
james    kate
james    bob
james    jhon
```

Hope you guys can understand my problem. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you want to join `followers` to `login` to get the followers for a login and join `login` again to get their names.

```
SELECT l1.username "User",
       l2.username "Following"
       FROM login l1
            INNER JOIN followers f
                       ON f.idsta = l1.id
            INNER JOIN login l2
                       ON l2.id = f.idfol
       WHERE l1.id = 3;
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/82f9d/2)

Comment: Thank you so much, that works like a charm. I tried something myself with INNER JOIN but I had the same progress as the query I posted here.